# Generate pre formatted excel file from CSV with node.js

Tags: node.js, excel, express

I am developing MEAN stack application.
I fetch a .csv file with some data. Then I need to convert this data to excel format.

I can achieve this with multiple npm pckages.

The main problem for me is that I need to generate/import data from csv to pre formatted excel file (I have excel template which I need to fill with data from csv file).

How can I achieve that?
I would be very happy if someone could suggest me some npm package or provide me with some documentation to achieve that with nodejs/express.

Thank you